# Updating Craft removed a channel from the CMS?

Tags: database, channels, updating

Anyone experienced this problem?

I have a dev site set up which we updated to 2.4.2702. After updating one of my section channels has disappeared from the CMS.

The entries for the channel are still showing and I can see the channel set up in `craft_sections` on the database so any ideas what has happened to it and why it is no longer in the CMS?

Comment: Which edition (Personal, Client or Pro) were you running before the update, and does Craft appear to be running the same edition now (check the CP footer)?

Comment: @mmikkel It seems to have switched it from pro 2.4.2692 to personal 2.4.2702?

Comment: Then that's your issue – Craft Personal is limited to a single channel. Your `license.key` file must've been overwritten/deleted somehow when you updated – which is weird unless this was a manual update? In any case, if you have purchased a license and don't have a copy of the `license.key` file you'll need to contact support@buildwithcraft.com to restore it. If this is a dev build and you haven't purchased a license, just click the upgrade link in the CP footer and then the "Test" button under _Craft Pro_ in the modal that appears.

Comment: @mmikkel cheers sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved with the above comments from @mmikkel

> *Craft Personal is limited to a single channel. Your license.key file must've been overwritten/deleted somehow when you updated – which is weird unless this was a manual update? In any case, if you have purchased a license and don't have a copy of the license.key file you'll need to contact support@buildwithcraft.com to restore it. If this is a dev build and you haven't purchased a license, just click the upgrade link in the CP footer and then the "Test" button under Craft Pro in the modal that appears.*

Comment: Great that you got it sorted. Can you elaborate a little – did you figure out why the license.key was wiped on update, and what did you do to restore it?

Comment: Hi @mmikkel no that is a mystery. The update was done using the craft update function in the CMS. So not sure if this is a bug with craft running on a dev site or not?